# How to calculate the percentage of each color in a JPG using PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to count the no. of colours in an Image and calculate its percentage from the total pixels. So far I've been able to get the no. of colours in an Image, its count and the total of pixels but I want to add the percentage of each colour next to the colour.

```
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter
import prettytable

img = Image.open("bnw.jpg")
size = w, h = img.size
data = img.load()

colors = []
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        color = data[x, y]
        hex_color = '#'+''.join([hex(c)[2:].rjust(2, '0') for c in color])
        colors.append(hex_color)

pt = prettytable.PrettyTable(['Color', 'Count'])

for color, count in Counter(colors).items():
    pt.add_row([color, count])
    total = sum(Counter(colors).values())

print(pt, total)
```

Here is the output:

```
+---------+--------+
|  Color  | Count  |
+---------+--------+
| #ffffff | 478329 |
| #fdfdfd |  932   |
| #fefefe |  1219  |
| #fbfbfb |  556   |
| #fafafa |  279   |
| #f8f8f8 |   89   |
| #f9f9f9 |  199   |
| #fcfcfc |  705   |
| #f7f7f7 |   50   |
| #040404 |  538   |
| #020202 |  883   |
| #010101 |  1196  |
| #000000 | 179583 |
| #080808 |   45   |
| #060606 |  176   |
| #050505 |  323   |
| #030303 |  726   |
| #0a0a0a |   17   |
| #070707 |   78   |
| #090909 |   28   |
| #f6f6f6 |   24   |
| #f5f5f5 |   12   |
| #0b0b0b |   8    |
| #f4f4f4 |   5    |
+---------+--------+ 666000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the total number of pixels using the image size. Then you can add the percentage in each row.

```
pt = prettytable.PrettyTable(['Color', 'Count', 'Percentage'])

total = w * h

for color, count in Counter(colors).items():
    pt.add_row([color, count, int(count/total * 100)])
   
print(pt, total)
```